# 正規表現で電話番号の文字列を正規化したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas, 正規表現

#### 前提

pandas の電話番号の列を正規表現にしたいです。
現在下記の読み込みcsvのように先頭の0が抜けたりハイフンなしがあります。
国際番号も含まれています。

読み込みcsv
※テスト電話番号です。

```
電話番号
8012345678
9012345678
90-1234-5678
080-1234-5678
110000000
06-1234-5678
(0)0 812345678
85212345678
(81)801 2345678
(852)123 45678
```

#### 実現したいこと

希望としては、下記のように正規表現で電話番号の列を置換したいです。

・国内の固定電話
03-○○○○-○○○○
045-○○○-○○○○
0456-○○-○○○○
04567-○-○○○○
0120-○○○-○○○

・携帯電話
090-○○○○-○○○○
080-○○○○-○○○○
070-○○○○-○○○○

・国際電話番号
(81)080-○○○○-○○○○もしくは81-080-○○○○-○○○○
(852)-○○○○-○○○○もしくは852-○○○○-○○○○

```
電話番号
080-1234-5678
090-1234-5678
090-1234-5678
080-1234-5678
110000000
06-1234-5678
08-1234-5678
(852)1234-5678
(81)080-1234-5678
(852)1234-5678
```

※110000000　桁数が多い電話番号に関して無視してそのままで記載したいです。
※正規表現でできない電話番号もそのまま無視してそのままで記載したいです。

正規表現のエラーメッセージが表示されます。

```
エラーメッセージ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    df['電話番号'] = df['電話番号'].replace(re.compile(pattern), df['電話番号'], regex=True)

ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-value and non-None to_replace
```

**コード**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

#ファイル名
filename1=r"C:\Users\test1.csv"

#csv読み込みdtype=objectと指定
df = pd.read_csv(filename1,dtype=object)

#列指定　タイプ確認
print(df['電話番号'])

#先頭に0を追加
df['電話番号'] = '0' + df['電話番号'].astype(str)
print(df)

#電話番号正規表現
pattern = r'[\(]{0,1}[0-9]{2,4}[\)\-\(]{0,1}[0-9]{2,4}[\)\-]{0,1}[0-9]{3,4}'

#正規表現で列置換　ハイフンを追加
df['電話番号'] = df['電話番号'].replace(re.compile(pattern), df['電話番号'], regex=True)
print(df)

#csv保存
df.to_csv(filename1,encoding='utf_8_sig',index=False)
```

#### 試したこと

上記のコードで試してみました。わかりづらいところも多いと思いますが、正規表現のエラーが表示されます。

参考ページ
[pythonで電話番号を正規表現で](https://qiita.com/yousuke_yamaguchi/items/422148e93eaf010d3532)

希望通りのように正規表現で電話番号の列で変換可能でしょうか。

原因が思い当たる方はご教授いただけませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

電話番号をどのように正規化したいかが分かっているならば[`Series`クラスの`apply`メソッド](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)を使ってみてはいかがでしょうか？正規化のルールをすべて把握してないので、国内携帯番号だけについて書くと次のようになります。

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
import io

text = '''
8012345678
9012345678
90-1234-5678
080-1234-5678
110000000
06-1234-5678
(0)0 812345678
85212345678
(81)801 2345678
(852)123 45678
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), names=['電話番号'])


def normalize_number_string(x):
    # y: xから先頭の0を取って、さらにハイフンをすべて取り除いたもの
    y = x
    y = y.lstrip('0')
    y = y.replace('-', '')

    # 7、8、9から始まる10桁の数字は、国内の携帯番号とみなして整形する。
    if re.match(r'^[789]\d{9}$', y):
        return f'0{y[:2]}-{y[2:6]}-{y[6:]}'

    # 必要ならば、ここに他の変換規則を追加する。
    ...

    # 形式不明であれば、もとの値を返す。
    return x


df['電話番号'] = df['電話番号'].apply(normalize_number_string)

print(df)
```

```
              電話番号
0    080-1234-5678
1    090-1234-5678
2    090-1234-5678
3    080-1234-5678
4        110000000
5     06-1234-5678
6   (0)0 812345678
7      85212345678
8  (81)801 2345678
9   (852)123 45678
```

なお、出ているエラーについてですが、[`Series`クラスの`replace`メソッド](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)は第1引数`to_replace`に置換対象を、第2引数`value`に置換後の値を指定します。第1引数を正規表現で与えるなら、第2引数もそれに応じた形にする必要があります（[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.sub)の第1、第2引数と同じ）。そこに`df['電話番号']`を渡しているのでpandasがエラーを出しています（正規表現にエラーがあるわけではない）。

また、参考にされているページは、正規表現によって電話番号を検索して抜き出すことを目的としています。正規表現によって電話番号を正規化することを目的としていません。`Series.replace()`に使うのであれば（そして1度で済ませようとするなら非常に巧みに）グループを設定した正規表現を与える必要があります。

**libphonenumber**

電話番号をハイフンが入った形に正規表現を使って正規化するのは（世界中の国別・市外・市内局番の仕様をすべて網羅するのが個人の力では）無理なので[Googleのlibphonenumber](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber)の[Pythonラッパー](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers)を使うことにすると、`normalize_number_string`は以下のようになります。

```py
def normalize_number_string(x):
    """電話番号xを正規化して返す。"""
    y = str(x)

    # 国際電話番号だと仮定して解釈してみる。うまくいったらそれを返す。
    try:
        z = phonenumbers.parse(f'+{y}', None)
        if phonenumbers.is_possible_number(z):
            if z.country_code == 81:  # 日本
                y = phonenumbers.format_number(z, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL)
                return y
            y = phonenumbers.format_number(z, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
            # ここでyがINTERNATIONAL形式になっていることに注意
            y = re.sub(r'^\+(\d+) ', r'(\1)', y)  # 国番号をカッコでくくる
            y = y.replace(' ', '-')  # 空白ではなくハイフンを区切りに
            return y
    except phonenumbers.NumberParseException:
        pass

    # 国内電話番号だと仮定して解釈してみる。うまくいったらそれを返す。
    try:
        z = phonenumbers.parse(y, 'JP')
        if phonenumbers.is_possible_number(z):
            y = phonenumbers.format_number(z, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL)
            return y
    except phonenumbers.NumberParseException:
        pass

    # 形式不明であれば、もとの値を返す。
    return x
```

```
            電話番号
0  080-1234-5678
1  090-1234-5678
2  090-1234-5678
3  080-1234-5678
4   011-000-0000
5   06-1234-5678
6  0081-234-5678
7  (852)12345678
8  080-1234-5678
9  (852)12345678
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。こちらの方法で試してみます。

Comment: 上記の方法で行ってみますたが、`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lstrip'`こちらのエラーが表示されます。空白も含まれているのでその影響だと思いっていましたが、`df[df['電話番号'].notna()]`を追加しても同じエラーが表示されます。

Comment: 電話番号の列に`str`ではなく`float`の値が入ってしまっています。（明らかに何かおかしい気がしますが）とりあえずエラーを直すなら、`normalize_number_string`の最初の`y = x`を`y = str(x)`にして明示的に文字列に変換してみてください。また、（おそらく期待した結果にならないと思うので）`normalize_number_string`の最初に`print(x)`などを入れて、実際に期待した電話番号の値が渡されているかチェックしてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`str`へ変換しましたら、いけました。

Comment: 度々、すいません、固定電話がある場合　正規表現も可能でしょうか。
こちらの9桁の固定電話も変換したいです。
`412345678`,`912345678`,`512345678`,`161234567`

Comment: `412345678`をどのように変換したいのでしょうか？そもそも`041`で始まる電話番号が存在しないので、市外局番と市内局番を分けられないのですが。。。 参考: https://www.soumu.go.jp/main_sosiki/joho_tsusin/top/tel_number/number_shitei.html

Comment: 自力で電話番号をハイフン区切りに変換するのは大変そうなので、何かライブラリを使った方がよいかと思われます。 例: https://rukurx.hatenablog.jp/entry/2019/11/22/080000

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
失礼しました。
市外局番1から9までの固定電話も含みたいです。
正規表現で可能でしょうか。
例：`047`、`092`、`011`、`052`

Comment: `phonenumbers`の情報もありがとうございます。そちらのライブラリでできるか。も確認します。

Comment: `phonenumbers`を使って正規表現で列を置換したいですが、関数に入れてみましたが上手く行かないです。下記のように指定しました。1行ずつ`for`文を使って置換した方が良いでしょうか。

`def normalize_number_string(x):`
 　`tel = x`
 　 `tel_hyphen = phonenumbers.parse(tel, 'JP')`
　　`tel=phonenumbers.format_number(tel_hyphen, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL)`

　　`return x`

　`df['電話番号'] = df['電話番号'].apply(normalize_number_string)`

Comment: どうも関数という概念をよく理解されておられないようなので、`phonenumbers`を使った`normalize_number_string`を追記いたしました。

Comment: 丁寧に教えてくれてありがとうございます。関数についてまだ勉強必要ですが、希望の結果になりました。。変換上手く行かない部分は手動で少し修正が必要ですが楽になりました。すごく勉強になりました。